# Magento 2 shows current product as recently viewed product

Tags: magento2, product, magento-2.1

I've got a problem with my Magento 2.1.4 store. I added recently viewed products block to the product page, but it keeps showing product I''m currently viewing as the 1st recently viewed product (example below).

Please help, I can't figure out why does it happen.

**Code that adds the recently viewed product block**

```
<referenceContainer name="content.aside">
    <block class="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed" name="related.recently.viewed"
           before="catalog.product.related" after="-"
           template="Magento_Reports::widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml">
        <argument method="setLimit">
            <argument name="limit" xsi:type="number">4</argument>
        </argument>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

**Example:**
[image: Recently viewed product]

Comment: How about your issue?

Comment: I went with the idea of comparing product ID's in viewed_grid.phtml - thanks @KhoaTruongDinh

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh slight problem that came up in testing - when there are no recently viewed products, ```$block->getProduct()``` works just fine, but when there are, this method returns ```null```. Any ideas?

Comment: You are being on product page or not? We can get the product when being in product page.

Comment: In ```catalog_product_view.xml``` I added a block with recently viewed products (template ```viewed_grid.phtml```). Now, when I'm trying to get product in this template using the abovementioned method, there are 2 cases: if there are no recently viewed products I can get the product on which page I am, but if there are recently viewed products, then ```$block-getProduct()``` returns ```null```

Comment: Let me check again...

Comment: Hey @KhoaTruongDinh, did you come up with something? Thank you!

Comment: Hey! Seem that it's a Magento bug. I'm trying to debug now.

Comment: I tried out a solution, where I'm doing this: $block->getLayout()->getBlock('related.recently.viewed')->setData('parent_product_id', $product->getId()) in another block on this page, but template with recently viewed items loads twice. On the 1st load there are no recently viewed products, but I can get the parent product id, on the other hand on the 2nd load there are recently viewed products, but I can get this parent product id. Any ideas?

Comment: You found the solution? Can you share?

Comment: No, I just wrote a comment above with another way that doesn't work, asking if you might have ideas regarding why does this block loads twice on a single product view.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh just posted an answer - take a look if you want :) Cheers, and thanks for all your help with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution - I'm going to share here in case someone needs it.

You need to overwrite `Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed` block and make sure to change this in `catalog_product_view.xml`.

In the overwritten block add method:

```
/**
 * Method returns array of recently viewed products without parent product
 *
 * @param array $recentlyViewedProducts
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function removeCurrentProductFromRecentlyViewed(array $recentlyViewedProducts)
{
    $parentProductId = $this->catalogSession->getlastViewedProductId();

    /** @var Product $product */
    foreach ($recentlyViewedProducts as $product) {
        if ((count($recentlyViewedProducts) == 1) && ($product->getId() == $parentProductId)) {
            return [];
        } elseif ($product->getId() == $parentProductId) {
            unset($recentlyViewedProducts[$product->getId()]);
        }
    }

    return $recentlyViewedProducts;
}
```

This get's current product ID and removes it from the array.

In `viewed_grid.phtml` you need to add the following section in the `if ($exist = ($block->getRecentlyViewedProducts() && $block->getRecentlyViewedProducts()->getSize())) ...` code:

```
$items = $block->getRecentlyViewedProducts();
$itemsWithoutParentProduct = $block->removeCurrentProductFromRecentlyViewed($items->getItems());
$items->removeAllItems();

$exist = false;

if (!count($itemsWithoutParentProduct) == 0) {
    foreach ($itemsWithoutParentProduct as $item) {
        $items->addItem($item);
    }

    $exist = true;
}
```

And it's done! Good luck everybody.

Comment: Yeah! Finally, you found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

1) I think there is an easy way to exclude the current product in Recently Viewed template by checking the current product in this template. For example, copy `vendor/magento/module-reports/view/frontend/templates/widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml` to your custom theme. We can get the current product

```
$currentId = $block->getProduct()->getId()
```

And then, we can use `if` condition to check. We will not print the recently viewed product if the id is equal to the current product id.

2) Seem that we can use the Plugin with `setRecentlyViewedProducts` : `vendor/magento/module-reports/Block/Product/Viewed.php::_toHtml()`

3) Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-reports/Model/Product/Index/AbstractIndex.php::getExcludeProductIds()`. This method is used in `vendor/magento/module-reports/Block/Product/AbstractProduct.php:: getItemsCollection()`. We can try to add the current product id to it.