# Remove current product from Recently Viewed Products on the product view page

Tags: magento2.2, recently-viewed

Basically the same question was asked here: [Magento 2 shows current product as recently viewed product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166998/magento-2-shows-current-product-as-recently-viewed-product) but the answer there doesn't apply for Magento 2.2 versions (or which ever version introduced the `recently viewed widget` as a `ui component`).

So I'm wondering if anyone has an idea how to remove the current product (which the customer is viewing on the product view page) from the recently viewed widget which is placed on the product view page?

I've tracked the functionality to `Magento_Catalog/ui_component/widget_recently_viewed.xml` and to the template file `Magento_Catalog/web/template/product/list/listing.html` which calls the `filteredRows` function from `Magento_Catalog/web/js/product/list/listing.js`.

But I'm not sure how to exclude the current product from the data source, so any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT** This seems to be solved by default in Magento 2.3.3+ versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Lez answer:
in my case, some products don't have prices. And I couldn't rely on finding the current product ID in DOM.

Instead, I've created a plugin for Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Listing\DataProvider.
**di.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Listing\DataProvider">
        <plugin name="ui_listing_data_provider"
            type="Vendor\Catalog\Plugin\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Listing\DataProvider"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And add there a current product ID from Magento Registry:

**DataProvider.php:**

```
class DataProvider
{
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * DataProvider constructor.
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * Adds current product ID for product listing ui component
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Listing\DataProvider $subject
     * @param array $result
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetData(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Listing\DataProvider $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');

        if (!empty($product) && $product instanceof Product) {
            $result['currentProductId'] = $product->getId();
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Let's say to Magento we're going to extend provider.js:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Catalog/js/product/provider': {
                'Vendor_Catalog/js/product/provider': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And then, just exclude the product with specified ID:

```
define([], function () {
'use strict';

    return function (Provider) {
        return Provider.extend({
            filterIds: function () {
                let ids = this._super();

                if (this.data.hasOwnProperty('currentProductId')) {
                    // Current product ID is set - we're on the product page
                    if (ids.hasOwnProperty(this.data.currentProductId)) {
                        // Current product ID exists in the list - exclude it
                        delete ids[this.data.currentProductId];
                    }
                }

                return ids;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll test this later on today, but it seems to be the right solution. Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to get this to work. I keep getting `this._super is not a function` JS error. So you probably didn't mention all the changes that you made.

Comment: filterIds extends the original filterIds function.
I've updated my answer with full provider.js content

Comment: This fixed the JS error, but I'm still having trouble getting it to work. I don't get the currentProductId property in `this.data`. So I presume something is wrong with the php part of the code. What is `UiDataProvider` in your afterGetData method? I used `\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Listing\DataProvider`. Also for registry, I used a construct with `\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry` is this correct? Is anything else missing maybe?

Comment: Yes, \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Listing\DataProvider & \Magento\Framework\Registry are correct. I've updated the answer with plugin class & di.xml.
Check if your plugin was called and if you're on the product page - "current_product" in the registry should be set

Comment: I managed to solve it. The problem was the `instanceof Product` part - should be `instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`. Works like a charm now :)

Comment: Cool!
And thank you for the idea where to start digging :)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution for Mage 2.2+ versions.

Override the `filterIds` function in `Magento_Catalog/web/js/product/provider.js` like this:

```
filterIds: function (ids) {
    var _ids = {},
    currentTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

    _.each(ids, function (id) {
        if (currentTime - id['added_at'] < ~~this.idsStorage.lifetime) {
            // Verify that the customer is on the product view page by looking for the data-product-id attribute in the product-info-main container.
            var current_product = $('.product-info-main .price-box').attr('data-product-id');
            if (current_product != '') {
                if (!(id['product_id'] == current_product)) {
                    _ids[id['product_id']] = id;
                }
            } else {
                _ids[id['product_id']] = id;
            }
         }
     }, this);

     return _ids;
 },
```

Also you have to define `jquery` in the same file, so you can use it to locate the `data-product-id` attribute.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiElement',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/product/storage/storage-service',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, _, utils, Element, storage, customerData) {
    'use strict';
```

This is probably not the best possible solution since some products might not have a price, but it suits my needs just fine.

A more thorough approach would be to get the current product id from backend and then remove it from the array of recently viewed products.